# ¿Cómo buscar una cadena de texto en un ckeditor?

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

Estoy utilizando `CKEDITOR` en mi proyecto de `Laravel`. Una de las funcionalidades que le incorporé perzonalizando un `plugin` fue que cuando seleccione un texto pueda obtener ese texto con el método:

```
var text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
alert( text );
```

Yo tengo un listado en un arreglo de acuerdos tomados en una reunión, pero cuando quiero editar un acuerdo de estos, quisiera que el usuario los editara pero que busque dentro de mi editor de texto `ckeditor`, lo que se iba a cambiar y sustituirlo por el nuevo acuerdo editado. O implementar una funcionalidad que me permita que cuando dé editar el acuerdo me seleccione dentro de mi `CKEDITOR` la cadena de texto como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo implementar esto? No tengo claro algún método propio de `CKEDITOR` que busque cadenas de texto y que utilizando quizás `selectElement`

Comment: Hay varios _plugins_ para eso, como [TextMatch](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/textmatch) o, si quieres mayor funcionalidad, [Find / Replace](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/find)

Comment: conoceras algun codigo que no se precisamente usando un plugin de ckeditor para esto? es que yo tengo un listado en un arreglo de acuerdos tomados en una reunión, pero cuando quiero editar un acuerdos de estos quisiera que el usuario los editará pero que buscara dentro de mi editor de texto ckeditor lo que se iba a cambiar y sustituirlo por el nuevo acuerdo editado

Comment: ¿En qué parte te estás complicando?